# Linux: перестают работать основные команды после выполнения скрипта, модифицирующего path

Tags: linux, bash, centos, oracle19c

Странное дело.

учусь ставить Oracle вот по такому руководству:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/oracle-db-19c-installation-on-oracle-linux-8

Соответственно, у меня Oracle linux 8.0 (это, как я понял, red hat с переименованной командой yum и другим источником пакетов по умолчанию).

Это запутанная инструкция из многих пунктов, о смысле которых приходится догадываться, но мой вопрос - довольно конкретный.

Вот я дошел до места в инструкции, когда создан пользователь с именем oracle, и у этого пользователя в директории `/home/oracle/scripts/` есть файл `/home/oracle/scripts/setEnv.sh` вот с таким содержимым:

```
    # Oracle Settings
    export TMP=/tmp
    export TMPDIR=\$TMP

    export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oraclelinux.localdomain
    export ORACLE_UNQNAME=cdb1
    export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
    export ORACLE_HOME=\$ORACLE_BASE/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
    export ORA_INVENTORY=/u01/app/oraInventory
    export ORACLE_SID=cdb1
    export PDB_NAME=pdb1
    export DATA_DIR=/u02/oradata

    export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:\$PATH
    export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH

    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
    export CLASSPATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:\$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

А дальше **начинается загадочное**.

я захожу пользовтаелем oracle. И у меня работают привычные простейшие команды: `ls`, `pwd` и т.п.

Потом я выполняю команду

`. /home/oracle/scripts/setEnv.sh`

то есть, я буквально выполняю этот файл.

И после этого у меня никакие привычные команды (`ls`, `pwd`) уже не работают, а просто пишут, что `-bash: ls: command not found`

я догадываюсь, что, скорее всего, в процессе выполения `setEnv.sh` как то неправильно модифицируется path, но я не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить у пользователя Oracle нужные переменные окружения и остаться с работающей командой ls? Спасибо!

Также, если Вы подскажете мне более понятное руководство по установке Oracle (в котором объясняется, **зачем** надо делать то, что там написано), я тоже буду рад.

Comment: Похоже, вы проигнорировали целое предложение в руководстве: «If you are not creating the file with the `cat` command, you will need to **remove the escape characters**.»

Comment: Ну да, мне как раз показалось подозрительным добавление слешей в path: `\$PATH`, а это оказывается экранирование для cat

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо!